# Debugging error: Kruskal Algorithm, ADT

Tags: c, algorithm, adt

Beginner of studying Graph in ADT, C language.

This is the code that debug had captured. The debugging result is `plist->cur was 0xCDCDCDCD`.(from DLinkedList.c) 
And Debug program said that upper code occurs error on these call sequences.

```
ConKruskalMST(&graph);(main code)
if (!IsConnVertex(pg, edge.v1, edge.v2));(ALGraphKruskal.c, line 172)
while (LNext(&(pg->adjList[visitV]), &nextV) == TRUE); (ALGraphKruskal.c, 
line 108)
*cur -> 0xCDCDCDCD{data = ?? next = ??} can't read memory of data, next
```

I couldn't understand why this was the error.
Would you help me to find the problem on this code? It will be very helpful for me. Total codes for Kruskal are under this line.

Thank you

P.S. These codes are in the book named "Introduction to Data Structures Using C for studying ADT".

Filename-> ALEdge.h / ALGraphKruskal.h / ArrayBaseStack.h / DLinkedList.h / PriorityQueue.h / UsefulHeap.h / ALGraphKruskal.c / ArrayBaseStack.c / DLinkedList.c / KruskalMain.c / PriorityQueue.c / UsefulHeap.c

[ALEdge.h]

```
#ifndef __AL_EDGE__
#define __AL_EDGE__
typedef struct _edge {
    int v1;
    int v2;
    int weight;
} Edge;
#endif
```

[ALGraphKruskal.h]

```
#ifndef __AL_GRAPH_KRUSKAL__
#define __AL_GRAPH_KRUSKAL__

#include "DLinkedList.h"
#include "PriorityQueue.h"
#include "ALEdge.h"
#include "ArrayBaseStack.h"

enum { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J };

typedef struct _ual {
    int numV;
    int numE;
    List * adjList;
    int * visitInfo;
    PQueue pqueue;
} ALGraph;

void GraphInit(ALGraph * pg, int nv);
void GraphDestroy(ALGraph * pg);
void AddEdge(ALGraph * pg, int fromV, int toV, int weight);
void ShowGraphEdgeInfo(ALGraph * pg);
int IsConnVertex(ALGraph * pg, int v1, int v2);
void ConKruskalMST(ALGraph * pg);
void ShowGraphEdgeWeightInfo(ALGraph * pg);

#endif
```

[ArrayBaseStack.h]

```
#ifndef __AB_STACK_H__
#define __AB_STACK_H__

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0
#define STACK_LEN   100

typedef int Data;

typedef struct _arrayStack {
    Data stackArr[STACK_LEN];
    int topIndex;
} ArrayStack;

typedef ArrayStack Stack;

void StackInit(Stack * pstack);
int SIsEmpty(Stack * pstack);

void SPush(Stack * pstack, Data data);
Data SPop(Stack * pstack);
Data SPeek(Stack * pstack);

#endif
```

[DLinkedList.h]

```
#ifndef __D_LINKED_LIST_H__
#define __D_LINKED_LIST_H__

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

typedef int LData;

typedef struct _node {
    LData data;
    struct _node * next;
} Node;

typedef struct _linkedList {
    Node * head;
    Node * cur;
    Node * before;
    int numOfData;
    int(*comp)(LData d1, LData d2);
} LinkedList;

typedef LinkedList List;

void ListInit(List * plist);
void LInsert(List * plist, LData data);

int LFirst(List * plist, LData * pdata);
int LNext(List * plist, LData * pdata);

LData LRemove(List * plist);
int LCount(List * plist);

void SetSortRule(List * plist, int(*comp)(LData d1, LData d2));

#endif
```

[PriorityQueue.h]

```
#ifndef __PRIORITY_QUEUE_H__
#define __PRIORITY_QUEUE_H__

#include "UsefulHeap.h"

typedef Heap PQueue;
typedef HData PQData;

void PQueueInit(PQueue * ppq, PriorityComp pc);
int PQIsEmpty(PQueue * ppq);

void PEnqueue(PQueue * ppq, PQData data);
PQData PDequeue(PQueue * ppq);

#endif __PRIORITY_QUEUE_H__
```

[UsefulHeap.h]

```
#ifndef __USEFUL_HEAP_H__
#define __USEFUL_HEAP_H__
#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

#define HEAP_LEN    100
#include "ALEdge.h"

typedef Edge HData;
typedef int PriorityComp(HData d1, HData d2);

typedef struct _heap {
    PriorityComp * comp;
    int numOfData;
    HData heapArr[HEAP_LEN];
} Heap;

void HeapInit(Heap * ph, PriorityComp pc);
int HIsEmpty(Heap * ph);

void HInsert(Heap * ph, HData data);
HData HDelete(Heap * ph);

#endif
```

[ALGraphKruskal.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ALGraphKruskal.h"
#include "DLinkedList.h"

int WhoIsPrecede(int data1, int data2);
int PQWeightComp(Edge d1, Edge d2);

int PQWeightComp(Edge d1, Edge d2) {
    return d1.weight - d2.weight;
}

void GraphInit(ALGraph * pg, int nv) {
    int i;

    pg->adjList = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List) * nv);
    pg->numV = nv;
    pg->numE = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nv; i++) {
        ListInit(&(pg->adjList[i]));
        SetSortRule(&(pg->adjList[i]), WhoIsPrecede);
    }

    pg->visitInfo = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * pg->numV);
    memset(pg->visitInfo, 0, sizeof(int) * pg->numV);

    PQueueInit(&(pg->pqueue), PQWeightComp);
}

void GraphDestroy(ALGraph * pg) {
    if (pg->adjList != NULL)
        free(pg->adjList);

    if (pg->visitInfo != NULL);
        free(pg->visitInfo);
}

void AddEdge(ALGraph * pg, int fromV, int toV, int weight) {
    Edge edge = { fromV, toV, weight };

    LInsert(&(pg->adjList[fromV]), toV);
    LInsert(&(pg->adjList[toV]), fromV);
    pg->numE += 1;

    PEnqueue(&(pg->pqueue), edge);
}

void ShowGraphEdgeInfo(ALGraph * pg) {
    int i;
    int vx;

    for (i = 0; i < pg->numV; i++) {

        printf("%c connects with: ", i + 65);

        if (LFirst(&(pg->adjList[i]), &vx)) {

            printf("%c ", vx + 65);

            while (LNext(&(pg->adjList[i]), &vx))
                printf("%c ", vx + 65);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int WhoIsPrecede(int data1, int data2) {
    if (data1 < data2)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int VisitVertex(ALGraph * pg, int visitV) {
    if (pg->visitInfo[visitV] == 0) {
        pg->visitInfo[visitV] = 1;
        printf("%c ", visitV + 65);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int IsConnVertex(ALGraph * pg, int v1, int v2) {
    Stack stack;
    int visitV = v1;
    int nextV;

    StackInit(&stack);
    VisitVertex(pg, visitV);
    SPush(&stack, visitV);

    while (LFirst(&(pg->adjList[visitV]), &nextV) == TRUE) {
        int visitFlag = FALSE;

        if (nextV == v2) {
            memset(pg->visitInfo, 0, sizeof(int) * pg->numV);
            return TRUE;
        }

        if (VisitVertex(pg, nextV) == TRUE) {
            SPush(&stack, visitV);
            visitV = nextV;
            visitFlag = TRUE;
        }
        else {
            while (LNext(&(pg->adjList[visitV]), &nextV) == TRUE) {

                if (nextV == v2) {
                    memset(pg->visitInfo, 0, sizeof(int) * pg->numV);
                    return TRUE;
                }

                if (VisitVertex(pg, nextV) == TRUE) {
                    SPush(&stack, visitV);
                    visitV = nextV;
                    visitFlag = TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
        if (visitFlag == FALSE) {
            if (SIsEmpty(&stack) == TRUE)
                break;
            else
                visitV = SPop(&stack);
        }   
    }
    memset(pg->visitInfo, 0, sizeof(int) * pg->numV);
    return FALSE;
}

void RemoveWayEdge(ALGraph * pg, int fromV, int toV) {
    int edge;

    if (LFirst(&(pg->adjList[fromV]), &edge)) {
        if (edge == toV) {
            LRemove(&(pg->adjList[fromV]));
            return;
        }
        while (LNext(&(pg->adjList[fromV]), &edge)) {
            if (edge == toV) {
                LRemove(&(pg->adjList[fromV]));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}


void RemoveEdge(ALGraph * pg, int fromV, int toV) {
    RemoveWayEdge(pg, fromV, toV);
    RemoveWayEdge(pg, toV, fromV);
    (pg->numE)--;
}

void RecoverEdge(ALGraph * pg, int fromV, int toV, int weight) {
    LInsert(&(pg->adjList[fromV]), toV);
    LInsert(&(pg->adjList[toV]), fromV);
    (pg->numE)--;
}

void ConKruskalMST(ALGraph * pg) {
    Edge recvEdge[20];
    Edge edge;
    int eidx = 0;
    int i;

    while (pg->numE + 1 > pg->numV) {
        edge = PDequeue(&(pg->pqueue));
        RemoveEdge(pg, edge.v1, edge.v2);
        if (!IsConnVertex(pg, edge.v1, edge.v2)) {
            RecoverEdge(pg, edge.v1, edge.v2, edge.weight);
            recvEdge[eidx++] = edge;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < eidx; i++) {
        PEnqueue(&(pg->pqueue), recvEdge[i]);
    }
}

void ShowGraphEdgeWeightInfo(ALGraph * pg) {
    PQueue copyPQ = pg->pqueue;
    Edge edge;

    while (!PQIsEmpty(&copyPQ)) {
        edge = PDequeue(&copyPQ);
        printf("(%c-%c), w:%d \n", edge.v1 + 65, edge.v2 + 65, edge.weight);
    }
}
```

[ArrayBaseStack.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ArrayBaseStack.h"

void StackInit(Stack * pstack) {
    pstack->topIndex = -1;
}

int SIsEmpty(Stack * pstack) {
    if (pstack->topIndex == -1)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

void SPush(Stack * pstack, Data data) {
    pstack->topIndex += 1;
    pstack->stackArr[pstack->topIndex] = data;
}

Data SPop(Stack * pstack) {
    int rIdx;

    if (SIsEmpty(pstack)) {
        printf("Error! \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    rIdx = pstack->topIndex;
    pstack->topIndex -= 1;

    return pstack->stackArr[rIdx];
}

Data SPeek(Stack * pstack) {
    if (SIsEmpty(pstack)) {
        printf("Error! \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return pstack->stackArr[pstack->topIndex];
}
```

[DLinkedList.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "DLinkedList.h"

void ListInit(List * plist) {
    plist->head = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    plist->head->next = NULL;
    plist->comp = NULL;
    plist->numOfData = 0;
}

void FInsert(List * plist, LData data) {
    Node * newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;

    newNode->next = plist->head->next;
    plist->head->next = newNode;

    (plist->numOfData)++;
}

void SInsert(List * plist, LData data) {
    Node * newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node * pred = plist->head;
    newNode->data = data;

    while (pred->next != NULL && plist->comp(data, pred->next->data) != 0) {
        pred = pred->next;
    }

    newNode->next = pred->next;
    pred->next = newNode;

    (plist->numOfData)++;
}

void LInsert(List * plist, LData data) {
    if (plist->comp == NULL)
        FInsert(plist, data);
    else
        SInsert(plist, data);
}

int LFirst(List * plist, LData * pdata) {
    if (plist->head->next == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    plist->before = plist->head;
    plist->cur = plist->head->next;

    *pdata = plist->cur->data;
    return TRUE;
}

int LNext(List * plist, LData * pdata) {
    if(plist->cur->next == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    plist->before = plist->cur;
    plist->cur = plist->cur->next;

    *pdata = plist->cur->data;
    return TRUE;
}

LData LRemove(List * plist) {
    Node * rpos = plist->cur;
    LData rdata = rpos->data;

    plist->before->next = plist->cur->next;
    plist->cur = plist->before;

    free(rpos);
    (plist->numOfData)--;
    return rdata;
}

int LCount(List * plist) {
    return plist->numOfData;
}

void SetSortRule(List * plist, int(*comp)(LData d1, LData d2)) {
    plist->comp = comp;
}
```

[KruskalMain.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ALGraphKruskal.h"

int main(void) {
    ALGraph graph;
    GraphInit(&graph, 6);

    AddEdge(&graph, A, B, 9);
    AddEdge(&graph, B, C, 2);
    AddEdge(&graph, A, C, 12);
    AddEdge(&graph, A, D, 8);
    AddEdge(&graph, D, C, 6);
    AddEdge(&graph, A, F, 11);
    AddEdge(&graph, F, D, 4);
    AddEdge(&graph, D, E, 3);
    AddEdge(&graph, E, C, 7);
    AddEdge(&graph, F, E, 13);

    ConKruskalMST(&graph);
    ShowGraphEdgeInfo(&graph);
    ShowGraphEdgeWeightInfo(&graph);

    GraphDestroy(&graph);

    return 0;
}
```

[PriorityQueue.c]

```
#include "PriorityQueue.h"
#include "UsefulHeap.h"

void PQueueInit(PQueue * ppq, PriorityComp pc) {
    HeapInit(ppq, pc);
}

int PQIsEmpty(PQueue * ppq) {
    return HIsEmpty(ppq);
}

void PEnqueue(PQueue * ppq, PQData data) {
    HInsert(ppq, data);
}

PQData PDequeue(PQueue * ppq) {
    return HDelete(ppq);
}
```

[UsefulHeap.c]

```
#include "UsefulHeap.h"

void HeapInit(Heap * ph, PriorityComp pc) {
    ph->numOfData = 0;
    ph->comp = pc;
}

int HIsEmpty(Heap * ph) {
    if (ph->numOfData == 0)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

int GetParentIDX(int idx) {
    return idx / 2;
}

int GetLChildIDX(int idx) {
    return idx * 2;
}

int GetRChildIDX(int idx) {
    return GetLChildIDX(idx) + 1;
}

int GetHiPriChildIDX(Heap * ph, int idx) {
    if (GetLChildIDX(idx) > ph->numOfData)
        return 0;

    else if (GetLChildIDX(idx) == ph->numOfData)
        return GetLChildIDX(idx);

    else {
        if (ph->comp(ph->heapArr[GetLChildIDX(idx)], ph->heapArr[GetRChildIDX(idx)]) < 0)
            return GetRChildIDX(idx);
        else
            return GetLChildIDX(idx);
    }
}

void HInsert(Heap * ph, HData data) {
    int idx = ph->numOfData + 1;

    while (idx != 1) {
        if (ph->comp(data, ph->heapArr[GetParentIDX(idx)]) > 0) {
            ph->heapArr[idx] = ph->heapArr[GetParentIDX(idx)];
            idx = GetParentIDX(idx);
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    ph->heapArr[idx] = data;
    ph->numOfData += 1;
}

HData HDelete(Heap * ph) {
    HData retData = ph->heapArr[1];
    HData lastElem = ph->heapArr[ph->numOfData];

    int parentIdx = 1;
    int childIdx;

    while (childIdx = GetHiPriChildIDX(ph, parentIdx)) {
        if (ph->comp(lastElem, ph->heapArr[childIdx]) >= 0)
            break;

        ph->heapArr[parentIdx] = ph->heapArr[childIdx];
        parentIdx = childIdx;
    }

    ph->heapArr[parentIdx] = lastElem;
    ph->numOfData -= 1;
    return retData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In DLinkedList.c

```
int LNext(List * plist, LData * pdata) {
   if(plist->cur->next == NULL)
       return FALSE;
   plist->before = plist->cur;
   plist->cur = plist->cur->next;

   *pdata = plist->cur->data;
   return TRUE;
}
```

The case where plist->cur is NULL is missed so. if you change the code to:

```
int LNext(List * plist, LData * pdata) {
   if(plist->cur == NULL)
       return FALSE;
   if(plist->cur->next == NULL)
       return FALSE;
   plist->before = plist->cur;
   plist->cur = plist->cur->next;

   *pdata = plist->cur->data;
   return TRUE;
}
```

It should work fine.

Comment: I did it as you said but it doesn't work... In case of under code, same problem occurs. If you are right, another problem will be possible in these codes but debug don't capture?

Comment: Also, Try debugging using the **step** rather than **next** to see the actual flow of the code.

Comment: In a solution code analyzing, warnings occured at NULL point dereference error in DLinkedList.c. I think warnings are about plist->head->next... Will those things have a problem on code about LNext??